# Webpack - Why is my bundle.js file minified by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, build-tools

I am learning react, and the online course I am following uses webpack. I didn't add any minifying or uglyfying options to my webpack.config but still my bundle.js is minified. I am not sure why or how to turn it off. I have attached my webpack.config.js and package.json. Thanks for your help.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

```js
{
  "name": "expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "learn react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "powpowpow",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.3.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using webpack 4 without a mode setting. Normally, you should have the following warning:

```
WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn 
more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
```

Add `mode: development` in your conf to disable minification and this warning.

Answer (score 14):

As you are using webpack 4

One of the ways is :

Inside [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) set `scripts` to either `development` or `production` mode

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

And now when you run `npm run dev` it will give you `bundle.js` but **not minified**.

But when you run `npm run build` it will give you a **minified bundle**

Answer (score 3):

Webpack 4 minimizes by default.

Try adding this to your `module.exports` in `webpack.config.js`.

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify the `mode` in your config file, by default webpack set `mode: production`.

 In production mode, the webpack minify the bundle by default.
Read more : https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification